# Java.Как конвертировать строку даты в UNIX время?

Tags: java, http, unix, время

В ответе `POST` запроса у `header` есть параметр `Date`

```
response.headers().getDate("Date");
```

Он содержит строку:

> Sat Nov 14 19:30:25 GMT+05:00 2015

Как мне перевести это время в UNIX формат?

Comment: Так вроде `com.squareup.okhttp.Headers.getDate(String name)` возвращает `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
String dateString = response.headers().getDate("Date");
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
long unixTime = (long)date.getTime()/1000;
```